# Gradle build boost

Tags: build-process, android-gradle-plugin

I my project I observed below task are taking almost 98% of build time

> App:compileDebugJava
>   App:dexDebug

Once Gradle developer fix incremental build support [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82411), we can get rid of with App:compileDebugJava

Just need to include below snip of script in your Top-level build file

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        configure(options) {
            incremental = true
        }
    }
}
```

Same short of thing I am looking for App:dexDebug

By the way I already using

```
android{
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        preDexLibraries false
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```

In addition with below properties in gradle.properties file

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
project.android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries=false
```

Please let me know that how can I boost App:dexDebug?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am doing the same thing, have brought down the compile time to 2 minutes which is still a lot.

Comment: @Jalpesh No, but in addition with that I am using SSD hardisk which help a little bit. If you use it too then it would save few more seconds (10-20 sec) for you.

Comment: Ok sir, I increased the max heap size to 6 G for now, I know it is not recommended, but is working for me and keeping the build time under 1 1/2 minutes...

Comment: @Jalpesh You are right. Increasing heap size will also reduce the compilation time and to do so I am using. _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms512m -Xmx6144m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=500m